# How to make require password when uninstalling program?

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, installation, uninstallation

I am developing windows app with c# for website blocking and children control. How to make require password when uninstalling program? And if only the user enters correct password the program uninstalls.

Comment: I wouldn't install such an application.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want this. You can require administrator rights to be required but if the user is an administrator why should he/she be required to enter a password to uninstall an application? This is what user permissions on a system are for...

Comment: Wouldn't admin group policies be a better approach?  If this is for a corporate environment, and you're forcing people to have the application, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: The app is for website blocking and children control, this is why I need password before uninstalling

Comment: Very confusing on what the problem is - If your "children" run as admins on the box you lost already. If not - there is no way to uninstall program installed for whole system without admin permissions/password...

Comment: I've seen enterprise grade antivirus software do this, in situations where the end-user "needs" administrative privileges. but not privileges to uninstall the antivirus

Comment: @Robert Harvey, what is your suggestion for a corporate requirements like what you said?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd-party applications that can do this, yes.  But, the better approach would be to use the built-in administrative tools in Windows itself.  For example, denying the end-user to add/remove programs within the add/remove programs wizard.

Comment: I would just assert UAC/Administrator and let windows "deny"/"accept" as appropriate.

Comment: @user2246674 - That's likely an even better approach.